# Dynamically resizing TextBox with scroll bar

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

Is it possible to have a scrolling (multiline) TextBox without explicitly setting the height? Here is my example code snippet:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="6"
      Grid.Column="2"
      Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Grid.Row="0">Heading</Label>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1"
             SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True"
             TextWrapping="Wrap"
             AcceptsReturn="True"
             VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"></TextBox>
</Grid>
```

The problem here is that the TextBox will resize itself depending on how many lines the user enters without resorting to instead staying the same size and scrolling.

Comment: Perhaps instead use the row count/line count?

Comment: @Ben setting the max/min lines does not help as it would not support dynamic resizing.

Comment: I meant if there was a way to count the lines of text, not the properties of the Textbox.

Comment: @Ben why would that matter?

Comment: Would MaxHeight do what you want? From your question it is a little bit hard to understand exactly what behavior would you like.

Comment: @Ladi I'd like it to operate exactly like the multiline WinForms text box.

Comment: WinForms text box will not automatically resize unless you set Anchor or Dock properties. So what behaviour exactly do you want? You can either have fixed size or dynamic size, in which case the text box will expand (and not display a scroll bar) until it hits some limit (e.g. max size, window size).

Comment: Remove `Height="Auto"` and make it either hard coded or something of that sort.

Comment: @vesan and when it's docked and dynamically resizing the scroll bar is still available. That doesn't seem to be the case with the WPF control.

Comment: So you just want the scroll bar to be visible at all time? Then you want `VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"`, not `Auto`.

Comment: @Anthony: I tried running your code and it seems to run perfectly as expected. Post the complete XAML and more details. Post some screenshots if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add  `VerticalAlignment="Top"`

```
  <Grid Grid.Row="6"
  Grid.Column="2"
  Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Grid.Row="0">Heading</Label>
    <TextBox 
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Grid.Row="1"
         SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True"
         TextWrapping="Wrap"
         AcceptsReturn="True"
         VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"></TextBox>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get you started. As you have not put your requirements clearly, it's difficult to put a proper solution. If you put your more clear requirements, I can make a better version for you.

```
<Window ...>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="476*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="45*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="8*"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="{Binding Value, ElementName=HorizontalSB}" Height="{Binding Value, ElementName=VerticalSB}" Margin="30,37,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <ScrollBar x:Name="VerticalSB" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="Auto" SmallChange="1" Minimum="50" Value="25" MaxHeight="250" Maximum="1000"/>
        <ScrollBar x:Name="HorizontalSB" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" SmallChange="10" Maximum="1000" Minimum="20" LargeChange="10" Value="75"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```